# two iframes concept in c#

Tags: c#, iframe

I have two iframes in home page. one iframe contain sidebar Iframe which has treeview, another is the content of respective treeview onclick.each treeview onclick has different page link dynamically.

Now I want to display the page in Content Iframe on treeview(which is in another iframe in same page)on click. this all has to done on code behind.

Thank you.

> ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Load", "window.parent.location.href =
>   'WorkDetailsMileStoneSubMileStoneMapping.aspx'; ");

This is the code behind i am using. if i use this it not targeting to iframe, instead it is replace the home page

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see what you've done already.  Also I don't see a reason why an iframe needs to be used here. Some description of your target implementation would help.

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Load", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location.href = 'WorkDetailsMileStoneSubMileStoneMapping.aspx'; </script>"); This is the code behind i am using. if i use this it not targeting to iframe, instead it is replace the home page

Comment: @Seminal, edit your question and post the code there, not in the comment.